# Excel VBA Copying - Move file with code

Tags: excel, vba

It is possible in to copy/move the file that is running the excel vba code to another location? Because after processing the data I need to put that file (where all the code is written) in a specific location.

Thanks
BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just SaveAs and delete the old file?

```
Dim OldPath As String
With ThisWorkbook
     OldPath = .FullName
     .SaveAs "New File Path"
     Kill OldPath
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can do that while the file with the code is open an running the code?

Comment: It is saving itself to another location, this works like a charm.
Just test it on a sample file.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm going to test it